# Attempt to write a readonly database After of 20 minutes of repeated queries

Tags: c#, sqlite, readonly, system.data.sqlite

My application makes one query to a `SQLite` database every 3 seconds, but after about 20 minutes, at the time of executing the command, it throws the exception `"Attempt to write a readonly database"`. I just need to read the database.

Imports:

```
using System.Data.Sqlite;
```

This is my connection string:

```
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Patch_here;Version=3;Compress=True;Read Only=True"
```

This is the method where throws the excepcion. This Method is executed every 3 seconds:

```
Double fecha = 0;
try
{
    sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlite_conn);
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Messages";

    //HERE throws the exception, when executes the command.
    fecha = Double.Parse(sqlite_cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); 

    sqlite_cmd.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     informarError(ex.Message);
}
return timestamp_To_Datetime(fecha);
```

Additionally, 
- My user has all privileges for this database.
- My SQLiteConnection just is opened one time for all queries.

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you explicitly call `Dispose` and not use a `using` statment? If a error happens and you go to your `catch(Exception ex)` block you will never dispose the object. Also you don't show how you handle the `SQLiteConnection` you should be making the connection with the command and disposing it too, not re-using it globally. ADO.NET is designed for short lived connections, not long lived shared connections. Depending on your SQLite library it likely implements connection pooling so the connection will be re-used anyway.

Comment: I tried too with a 'using' statement but isn't the solution.
My SQLiteConnection just is opened one time for all queries.

Answer (score 0):

(I know, this is rather old. Maybe this is help for another person..)

I had a similar problem:
Database is under (write) load (is filled with an C/C++ program). At the same time a C# program send periodically a select count(*). Sometimes (very rare) it except with the error mentioned.

I "solved" this by removing "Read Only=True" from the connect string.